# How to get available CSS classes for an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a document with elements like this:

```
<ul class="fx-startpoint">
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>other text</li>
</ul>
```

At first I need to look with jQuery for all elements having a class starting with `fx-`. I think this is possible with `$("class=^fx-")` but then I need to look if there are other classes for this element available in a CSS file starting with `fx-` but they aren't currently set to the element or sub elements (like the li's).

How could I do this with jQuery/jQueryUI?

Comment: You actually need [`$('class^=fx-')`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).  jQuery can't search for whether classes are defined in your CSS, unfortunately, but you CAN easily test whether a given class exists in the DOM by checking `if ($('.some-class').length > 0)`

Comment: You would need a CSS parser written in JavaScript to do this, and setting everything up is not going to take five minutes. Are you sure your ultimate aim cannot be achieved in some other way?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,... but i think it's possible... i found something like this but thats not finally what i need...
http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/TKHpV/5/

Comment: Does that syntax really work? class is an attribute, wouldn't you need to do `$('[class^=fx]')`?

Comment: @mori57 You are of course correct.

Comment: You can use `document.stylesheets` to access the stylesheets applied to the document, and search for `.fx-` in them.

Comment: @mori57... your selector finds all objects which has already a fx class defined... but in the css (file) could be more like "ul.fx-ending_1000" or "ul.fx-ending_1000 li.fx-ending_800" that currently not set but i need to find it to switch to this class that i'm currently not known because they aren't currently set to the class attribute...

Comment: @Barmar: It's like the jsfiddle example... but i don't know how to change the fiddle that it only finds all fx... classes in document.stylesheets...

Comment: @HR123: Yes, but jQuery isn't designed to parse CSS files, just HTML markup, last I checked. To parse the CSS, you have to follow the same pattern that the jsFiddle you linked follows, using pure-Javascript methods.

Comment: Change the loop in the fiddle to do `if (/\.fx-/.test(rules[i].selectorText))` to find rules for `fx-XXX` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fork of the jsFiddle that the OP posted: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/kgqXY/

```
function GetAppliedCssRules($element) {
    var appliedRules = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < document.styleSheets.length; x++) {
        var rules = document.styleSheets[x].cssRules;
        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            var txt = rules[i].selectorText;
            if (txt.indexOf('.fx-') > -1) {
                appliedRules.push(txt);
            }
        }
    }
    return appliedRules;
}
```

Specifically, you're just changing the search to look for .fx-, which can be done with a simple .indexOf. Regex is also possible (as several other posters mentioned).

Comment: This breaks with the most *trivial* changes to the selectors, such as the example I gave in my answer, `.foo, .fx-bar { ... }`. Not to mention `div.fx-foo` and such.

Comment: No, `div.fx-foo` does work. See the full jsFiddle... I put in such a rule in the CSS (look for `a.fx-doop`). If I were looping through looking at markup with that format, you are quite correct... it would fail, but the premise here seems to be scanning the CSS rules.

Comment: As you can see from this version, it even works with mixed selectors like `hr, .fx-doop, .blah-blah` : http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/kgqXY/7/

Comment: Thanks, at works but not perfect...
It finds on all Elements the FX... and also if i say "li.fx-ping" and remove the others... the function returns results even if i click on the body or other objects and not only on the LI ...

Answer (score 1):

The selector `class=^fx-` would only find elements like this:

```
<div class="fx-foo bar">...</div>
```

...and not ones like this:

```
<div class="bar fx-foo">...</div>
```

...because the `fx-` doesn't appear at the *beginning* of the attribute. If you may have the second form, sadly your only option is to look at *all* elements and filter out the ones that don't have an `fx-xxx` class on them. There is currently no selector for "contains a word starting with".

As for finding all rules defining a class selector starting with `fx-`, you can do that. [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.styleSheets) gives you a list of all stylesheets applied to the current document. Each stylesheet object has a list of the rules defined for it (this will be either `cssRules` or just `rules` depending on age and brand of browser). Each rule ([`CSSStyleRule` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleRule)) will have information about the rule, including `selectorText` giving you the full selector for the rule. So you can parse that selector to see if it defines a class rule starting with `fx-`. Be sure to allow for commas when looking at the selector (for instance, `.foo, .fx-bar { ... }`), and beware that parsing selector strings, though not *hard*, is non-trivial.

Comment: hi thanks,
i think it's somethink like this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/TKHpV/5/

but i don't know how to change it that it will only finds fx-... styles. could you help me please to change it? thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
var classList =$('#divId').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

classList return an array of classes :
Then you can iterate and find the one you want by.

```
var classList =$('#divId').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
if (item === 'someClass') {
   //do something
}
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want to know the classes of a particular element, he wants to find all the possible classes in his stylesheet that begin with `fx-`.